# MUI Static datepicker sx prop is not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker

I need to disable default dialogue action buttons in mui datepicker but that `sx` props are not working

Here, is my code which I used for datepicker component:

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
    <StaticDatePicker
        sx={{
            ".MuiDialogActions-root": {
                display: "none",
                backgroundColor: "red !important",
            },
        }}
        showToolbar={false}
        value={selectedDate}
        views={["month", "year"]}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
        toolbarFormat={false}
        pickersToolbar={false}
    />
</LocalizationProvider>;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove the buttons but have the bg red then by `display: 'none'` you cant view the MuiDialogActions buttons root which includes the row.

You can try something like this which will now hide the individual buttons but display the bg as red

```
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
    <StaticDatePicker
      sx={{
        '.MuiDialogActions-root': { backgroundColor: 'red !important' },
        '.MuiButtonBase-root': { display: 'none', backgroundColor: 'red !important' },
      }}
      showToolbar={false}
      views={['month', 'year']}
      toolbarFormat={false}
      pickersToolbar={false}
    />
  </LocalizationProvider>
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-maria-n2k54y?file=/src/Demo.js)